# Why can I pass a vector to some functions and not others?

Tags: r, vector, vectorization

Can someone explain why this fails when the function is Vectorized? I thought Vectorization was just pre-allocation of memory. If I pass a vectorized parameter to `outer` it works fine, why cant I pass one to any function in general?

This works:

```
Fun <- function(a,b) sum(a+b)
VecFun <- Vectorize( Fun )
outer(1:3,1:3,VecFun)   #works perfectly, by which I mean it runs and returns a result
```

This doesnt:

```
a.trial<-function(){sample(c(0,0,0,1),1,replace=T)} 

a.trial.vectorized<-Vectorize(a.trial)

a.distrib<-replicate(a.trial.vectorized,10000) #has error when runs why, it follows the same pattern as the working example above
#a.distrib<-replicate(a.trial(),10000)   #works without error
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to define "works" and "fails" for us too.... And, what part of the function are you trying to vectorize?

Comment: I updated the comments to try to make that clearer. I am trying to vectorize the entire function. I am thinking about the fact that `outer` only accepts vectorized input,  but most stuff requires a function with parameters

Comment: What do you expect the output of `replicate(a.trial(), 10000)` to be? The first argument to `replicate` is a number specifying the number of replications. Also, notice that you're running `a.trial()` in the latter, and just `a.trial.vectorized` (without the `()`) in the former.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I was trying to copy the same formatting as the working `outer` example above using a function I created.